What is the performant way to store and query graph like data?
Entity Relationship Diagram
I have relationship tables representing above graph with just ids in them
CREATE TABLE USER_ORG (
  USER_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  ORG_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(USER_ID);

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_ORG (
  ACC_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  ORG_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(ACC_ID);


CREATE TABLE ROLE_ORG (
  ROLE_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  ENTITY_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(ROLE_ID);

CREATE TABLE ENTITY_ACC (
  ENTITY_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  ACC_ID STRING(100) NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(ENTITY_ID);

These relationships will be fed from some external systems this way.
What would be the most performant way to answer queries like:

Give me all users for a role_id=1
Give me all orgs for a role_id=1

This is just a subset of relationships we have. The dataset is pretty huge. Simple join queries during the retrieval might put load on the server.
Created views with complex join queries.

Good news, we just announced native graph support in Spanner!
You can find the announcement here
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-spanner-graph and the actual documentation here https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/graph/overview
Hope that helps!

thank you!!! this has been a game changer for our team. we've already been using spanner as a graph database for years so it's been very natural/easy for us to integrate this new feature. awesome work.
